# Do I need to find a maximum matching to get the matching number of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, matching-theory

Let’s say we are talking about a simple undirected graph with no loops and no multiple edges. But not necessarily bipartite. And we need to find its matching number. Do we have to find a maximum matching first or can we just apply some “quick” spectral theory magic to get the matching number directly? And by “quickly” I mean better than $O(e\sqrt{n})$, at which point we can just use [Micali-Vazirani general graph maximum matching algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4594).

Comment: MV80 didn't instantly decode to a matching algorithm for me, so you might like to make that more explicit.

Comment: @BenBarber, good point, replaced with a proper algorithm name and a link